# validate vat number is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form for a user introduce some data, the vat number and country. When the user enter some data and click in "Go to step 2" is made an ajax request to the store() method and here should be be validated the vat number based on the selected country.

But its not working, the "`dd($request->country);`" shows null. Do you know why?

Html:

```
<form method="post" id="step1" action="">

...
<div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
            @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value="">{{$country}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="vat"
               class="text-gray">VAT</label>
        <input type="text" id="vat"
               name="vat"
               class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

// store() method

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

      ...

        $rules = [];

        foreach ($request->question_required as $key => $value) {
            $rule = 'string|max:255'; 

            if ($value) {
                $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
            }
            $rules["question.{$key}"] = $rule;
        }

        if ($all) {

            $rules["name.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
        }

        // the issue is here, country is null
        dd($request->country);
        dd(substr($request->country, 0, 2) . $request->vat);

        //Validator::validate( substr($request->country, 0, 2).$request->vat); // false (checks format + existence)

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors = json_decode($errors);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $errors
            ], 422);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);

    }

// jQuery that do an ajax request
```

Comment: share your ajax code

Comment: Value attribute is blank `<option value="">{{$country}}</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing value into your  tag . Php is not getting any value from your input so its showing null

Comment: Like this "@foreach($countries as $k => $country)
                            <option value="{{$k}}">{{$country}}</option>
                        @endforeach" it works but then appears: "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::validate() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Facades/Facade.php on line 221". Do you know why?

Comment: Check your validation. Your validation is expecting array.

Comment: For your country code error you can create a file and store country data and then maybe convert into the country code. A quick google led me to this data  https://gist.github.com/maephisto/9228207. Have a look it might suit your need

Comment: Im passing the country and vat like "        Validator::validateFormat($request->country . $request->vat);
"  and appears Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Factory::validateFormat()" and internal server error 500.

Comment: There is no method validateFormat. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators
have a look at this for your validation

Comment: Thanks the method is a method of the package " dannyvankooten/laravel-vat".

Comment: I think you forgot to import the validator library 
`use DvK\Laravel\Vat\Facades\Validator;`

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears "Cannot use DvK\Laravel\Vat\Facades\Validator as Validator because the name is already in use".  Because in this controller I also have use Validator to validate the other fields that dont use any package. So I have this two uses "use Validator;
use DvK\Laravel\Vat\Facades\Validator;
".

Comment: If I remove "use Validator;" then that error above dont appears, but it appears this "Call to undefined method DvK\Laravel\Vat\Validator::make()".

Comment: You can use alias.`use DvK\Laravel\Vat\Facades\Validator as AnotherValidator`

AnotherValidator::validateFormat()

Comment: Thanks, now any error appears but the validation is not working, if I select a country and add an invalid vat number it returns code 200.

Comment: The "        $vatValidator = VatValidator::validate($request->country . $request->vat);
" returns true our false.

Comment: It should return true or false since its validating the data :P. What do you want it to do?

Comment: Thanks I would like to show a message, vat is valid or vat is invalid depending on if is true or false. Do you know how that can be achieved?

Comment: just use if statment to check and then maybe pass errors to errorbag if there was error. and you can fetch errors in your frontend as $errors

Comment: Thanks the issue is that the errors are empty when a vat is invalid in the network tab appears: "{success: false, errors: []}
errors
:
[]
success
:
false".

Comment: `$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
        $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
    }
});`